# Expose indexPath to configureCell

Tags: xlpagertabstrip

Currently configureCell only has access to the cell and IndicatorInfo. In my use case, I would like to know the indexPath of the cell so that I know which cell I am configuring and customize accordingly. Specifically we want to very first cell (indexPath 0) to display slightly different from the rest of the cells.

IndicatorInfo is currently a struct, so I can't subclass it to add another field to store the indexPath.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the definition of configureCell() and add indexPath to it as it is being called in collection view's cellForItemAt function :

collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell

So basically, follow the steps below:

1. Go to file -> **ButtonBarPagerTabStripViewCOntroller.swift**
2. Look for **configureCell()** function.
3. Add **indexPath: IndexPath** as one of the arguments in the definition
4. Check for usage of configureCell() and pass the indexpath in the function call.
5. When you will start editing this file, it will ask you to unlock it. You will have to allow that in the prompt.
6. Now when you override your configureCell() function, it will give you the indexPath as well.

Refer the below screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the information on how to do it! So it sounds like it isn't supported by default, thus the suggestion to change the source files of the library to add in the functionality? Wonder if this is something the author would consider adding?

Comment: Yeah. Maybe. I did try out ways to make it happen without this change. But this seems to be the cleanest solution. Accept it if it makes sense to you. Thanks. @FabeTob